# Single custom MySQL Query or multiple Hibernate queries, which is more efficient?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to get all columns from 5 tables. The result set can return up to 1000 rows.

Is it better to write a single custom query in MySQL to fetch all the data or use 5 Hibernate queries to fetch the data?

Conditions - 
In Table 1, the index is a combination of the primary key and another column on which the database is partitioned. In the remaining tables, the primary key of Table 1 is the foreign key and has the same column in remaining tables for the table partitioning.

(Due to some constraints - 
1. this data cannot be cached. 
2. Paginated calls are not feasible.
3. Eager or Lazy Fetching supported by Hibernate cannot be utilised)

Comment: The rule-of-thumb is 'the fewer round trips to the database, the better' - '1' being optimal

Answer (score 0):

I will always avoid HQL when the query is going to be complicated.

The value of Hibernate or other ORM are productivity and convenience. They can never outsmart a good developer.

Whatever Hibernate generated are still SQL Query. They can NEVER be more efficient than well written SQL queries.